# can I combine clr-based targets in MSBuild for c++ file?

Tags: c++, msbuild

Is it possible to call all types of targets in an MSBuild project file that starts as a C++ project file?

Perhaps that question is not quite accurate, but my intention is to use targets from the MSBuild extention pack along with the new C++ targets for VS 2010.

I'm guessing the need for the new C++ targets is to have some functionality that is compatible with the native code aspects of a native c++ vs projet file.

But my question is whether the normal MSBuild targets (which I've always thought were CLR-based) will also be available to the same project file along with the MSBuild extension pack targets.

Thanks,

Kimball Johnson

Comment: Well, sure, whatever .targets you `<Import>` in your project file.  Ask a better question to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to import and utilize the functionality provided by the MSBuild Extension Pack just fine -- it does not matter what language the tasks were written in or what language source code other tasks in your MSBuild project file are compiling. They're all just MSBuild tasks.